# Undefined type 'Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType' and 'Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface' also OptionsResolver is undefined

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have generated a project as skeleton and installed Form using `composer require form` and I generated using `php bin/console make:form` but it is showing undefined for all AbstractType, FormBuilderInterface and OptionsResolver.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('mobile')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: When running composer did any errors appear? What does `composer show symfony/form` show?

Comment: I suppose you could also check vendor/symfony/form to verify it has been installed.  Might even run 'composer dump-autoload'.  Sometimes composer fails and I don't even notice.  And where exactly are you getting these undefined notices?  Inside your IDE?  Sometimes it seems like my IDE does not always pickup new code and needs to have it's cache cleared.  Clearing the Symfony cache won't hurt either.

Answer (score 2):

You have to refresh your code editor or close and open your code editor

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Cumbersome as it is, the solution that worked for me was just closing and reopening my IDE (VS Code). Problem solved.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32164204)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `symfony/form` with the following command:

```
composer require symfony/form
```

Then, close and open again your IDE